# Open ID with Google and dotnetopenauth - Passing query string

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth, google-apps

I have some code that uses Google Apps as an Open ID provider to authenticate to my web application that is based on the example https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_dotnet.

It all works as expected. However, when redirected to the Google Login screen, the 'Stay Signed In' checkbox is selected by default. I have found that if I manually add &rm=false to then end of the URL, the checkbox is unselected, which I believe is a more secure default option.

My question is, how can I pass &rm=false in my code. I've looked at AddCallbackArguments but this doesn't seem to be the way to do it.

Code is

```
    private static readonly HostMetaDiscoveryService GoogleAppsDiscovery = new HostMetaDiscoveryService
    {
        UseGoogleHostedHostMeta = true,
    };
    private static readonly OpenIdRelyingParty relyingParty;

    static login()
    {
        relyingParty = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

        relyingParty.DiscoveryServices.Clear();
        relyingParty.DiscoveryServices.Insert(0, GoogleAppsDiscovery);
    }

    protected void buLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IAuthenticationRequest request = relyingParty.CreateRequest("mydomain");
        request.RedirectToProvider();
    }
```